# C++ to Java DepthFirstSearch translation

Tags: java, c++, code-translation

I have to translate a C++ source code into Java. Unfortunately, I've never been taught C++. Most of it is fairly easy, but I could use a bit of help.

```
void DepthFirstSearch(HeadNode *V[MaxCities], bool *Visited, int Start)
{
    //display each cited as it is visited
    cout << endl << V[Start]->City;
    //mark city as visited
    Visited[Start] = true;

    //continue depth first search
    CityNode *C;
    int NewStart;

    C = V[Start]->FirstCity;
    while(C != NULL){
        NewStart = C->Vertex;
        if(!Visited[NewStart])
            DepthFirstSearch(V,Visited,NewStart);
        C = C->NextCity;
    }//end while
}//end DepthFirstSearch
```

The line:

```
cout << end1 << V[Start]->City;
```

is particularly confusing. Any help?

Comment: That is not `end1` (end-one).  That is `endl` (end-el).

Answer (score 2):

`HeadNode *V[MaxCities]` is an array of pointers pointing to HeadNode objects. In Java its just like an array.

To get values or methods from to objects pointer you use the `->` operator.
In Java its some kind of `.` oprtator from objects.

`cout` is an outputstream which writes to stdout, in Java this would be System.out.print()

`<<` Operator is used to write into this stream.

`endl` like the new line characters `\r\n`

Answer (score 1):

> the line cout << end1 << V[Start]->City; is particularly confusing.
>   Any help?

would translate to:

```
System.out.print("\r\n" + v[Start].City);
```

There are guides available online by searching [Google](http://google.com/) for "cpp to java - [function]" ([function] being replaced by "cout", in this case.)